# Round floats in pandas multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I am given a pandas multiindex DataFrame indexed with floats. Consider the following example:

```
arrays = [[0.21,0.21,0.21,0.22,0.22,0.22,0.23,0.23,0.23],
          [0.81,0.8200000000000001,0.83,0.81,0.8200000000000001,0.83,0.81,0.8200000000000001,0.83]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 2), index=arrays)

df

#               0           1
# 0.21  0.81    -2.234036   -0.145643
#       0.82    0.367248    -1.471617
#       0.83    -0.764520   0.686241
# 0.22  0.81    1.380429    1.546513
#       0.82    1.230707    1.826980
#       0.83    -1.198403   0.377323
# 0.23  0.81    -0.418367   -0.125763
#       0.82    0.682860    -0.119080
#       0.83    -1.802418   0.357573
```

I am given this DataFrame in this form. Now, if I want to retrieve the entry `df.loc[(0.21, 0.82)]` I get an error because the index doesn't really carry `0.82` but `0.8200000000000001`. I don't know in advance where these problems occur in the index. How can I address this problem? My idea is to round both levels of the multiindex to the significant number of decimals, which is 2 in this case. But how can that be done? Is there a better solution?

Comment: _Is there a better solution?_ That depends on the specifics of the situation; What the data is, what it's being used for, etc. _My idea is to round both levels of the multiindex to the significant number of decimals, which is 2 in this case. But how can that be done?_ Have you tried anything, done any research? A simple web search for "pandas round numbers" gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using integer numbers instead: multiply your floating-point numbers by 100 (or 1000) and convert to ints:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
             (df.index.levels[0] * 100).astype(int),
             (df.index.levels[1] * 100).astype(int)])
```

Integer numbers are precise, unlike floating-point numbers. Now, you can use `df.loc[(21, 82)]` to access your data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rename` function to apply a function to each value of your `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.rename(index=lambda val: round(val, 2))

print(df.loc[(.21, .82)])
0    0.260015
1   -0.233822
Name: (0.21, 0.82), dtype: float64
```

However I'm not sure if having floats as specific keys due to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html
(brief example)

```
>>> .1 + .1 + .1 == .3
False
```

Though I'm curious as to what others think of this. Because I'm not sure of the realistic possible issues you'd encounter.

You could always truncate your floats to strings and then access your dataframe via strings instead to ensure accuracy:

```
df = df.rename(index="{:.2f}".format)

print(df.loc[("0.21", "0.82")]) # note that the leading 0 is important here now
0    0.260015
1   -0.233822
Name: (0.21, 0.82), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the last one. It's also useful.